# Jersey Client: Cache-Manager for Conditional GET?

Tags: java, http, caching, jersey

Jersey has wonderful support for server-side handling of Preconditions to respond to a Conditional-GET-request.

On the client-side it seems a bit less elegant/manual. As far as I know you'd need to store the metadata of the entity yourself (etag, last-modified header) and make a decision, when to set which headers, evaluate the response code, update your local cache of entity/metadata ... etc.

Do you know of a ready, free implementation that wraps up the conditonal GET? I found [this example](http://sleeplessinslc.blogspot.com/2009/03/example-of-caching-with-rest-using.html), where the poster is using `CacheManager` and `CacheEntry`; I suspect his own implementation. Shouldn't this be part of Jersey Client itself?

Comment: RESTeasy [has a "broswer cache" implementation](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/tree/master/jaxrs/resteasy-client/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/cache), but it is specific to RESTeasy, and if you want it, you need to take the entire client implementation that comes with it. Or you can take some notes from it for your own implementation :-). Theoretically, though, you can add the RESTeasy dependency and just add the browser feature to the Jersey client. You can exclude any transitives, as you wouldn't be using anything RESTeasy is dependent on. It all standard JAX-RS code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it should be part of the Jersey Client itself. You can register interest here: [JERSEY-100](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-100?jql=project%20%3D%20JERSEY%20AND%20issuetype%20in%20(Improvement%2C%20%22New%20Feature%22)%20AND%20text%20~%20%22cache%20client%22) The ticket is closed because "it has collected only 1 support votes and has not been updated" in 2015. I am "watching" this issue.

Comment: The link you shared no more exist.